# exception javax.servlet.ServletException: Communication link failure: java.io.EOFException

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

Hi
I develpoed a Web applicaton by using the JSP and MySql.That comes a Communication Link Failure Error.I tried up to my Knowledge, yet i didn't solve.Kindly help him and give the soluation.

Platform : Linux
S/w : java 1.5.0
Server : apache tomcat 5.5.9
DB : mysql-connector-java-5.0.5.jar

STACKTRACE:

java.sql.SQLException: Communication link failure: java.io.EOFException, underlying cause: null

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **

java.io.EOFException

STACKTRACE:

java.io.EOFException
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:1395)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:1539)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:1930)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1168)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1279)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQuery(MysqlIO.java:1225)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:2278)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:2237)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:2218)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.setAutoCommit(Connection.java:548)
    at cafe.admanya.data.ConnectionPool.getUserConnection(ConnectionPool.java:16)
    at cafe.admanya.product.ProductData.getProductDetails(ProductData.java:31)
    at org.apache.jsp.productDetails_jsp._jspService(productDetails_jsp.java:74)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:331)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:679)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:399)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:301)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:183)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:125)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:107)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:78)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:383)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:200)
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:775)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:704)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:897)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)

** END NESTED EXCEPTION **

```
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:1714)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:1930)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1168)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1279)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQuery(MysqlIO.java:1225)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:2278)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:2237)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:2218)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.setAutoCommit(Connection.java:548)
at cafe.admanya.data.ConnectionPool.getUserConnection(ConnectionPool.java:16)
at cafe.admanya.product.ProductData.getProductDetails(ProductData.java:31)
at org.apache.jsp.productDetails_jsp._jspService(productDetails_jsp.java:74)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:331)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:679)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:399)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:301)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:183)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:125)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:107)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:78)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:383)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:200)
at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:775)
at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:704)
at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:897)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

** END NESTED EXCEPTION **

Answer (score 1):

I think that this means that your servlet's JDBC connection to the MySQL database has been closed.  Your application needs to discard it and open a new one.

Comment: The same way that you did it in the first place.  Alternatively, if you used a connection pool, it should take care of this automatically.

Comment: I am using connection pool only.

Comment: So what happens if you return the JDBC connection to the pool, get another one and try again?

Comment: Sorry i am using mysql-connector-java-3.0.17-ga-bin.jar, is it fine or i have to use any other connector?